# Action<Task> implementation

Tags: c#, task

I need to create two methods for Task, each ot them will be similar to ContinueWith(), but will execute contunuation in main UI thread.

Overload method with parameters `Action` , `Action<Task>`

Method returns Task(for overloads with Action). Returned task must finish only after main Task and continuation
are completed.

Is it right implemetation function with `Action`? And how to implement second case with `Action<Task> input` with `Returned task must finish only after main Task and continuation`

I implemented

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        WorkAsync WA = new WorkAsync();
        Action firstaction = new Action(WA.Count);
        WA.Work(firstaction, uiScheduler);

        Action<Task> secondaction = new Action<Task>(); //What should be here?
        WA.Work(secondaction, uiScheduler);
    }
    public class WorkAsync
    {
        public Task Work(Action input, TaskScheduler uiSchedule)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(input).ContinueWith((e) => { Console.WriteLine("Done"); }, uiSchedule);
        }
        public Task Work(Action<Task> input, TaskScheduler uiSchedule)
        {
            /// What should be here?
        }

        public void Count()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like basic `await` should be enough... Why do you need such complex code?

Comment: I think you have your signature wrong for the second method - `public Task Work(Action<Task> input, TaskScheduler uiSchedule)` - it seems to me that it should be `public Task Work(Task current, Action input, TaskScheduler uiSchedule)`. Otherwise is appears that you're doing some sort of impossible recursive task.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, it's task to implement with Action<Task>.

Comment: `I need to create two methods for Task, each ot them will be similar to ContinueWith(), but will execute contunuation in main UI thread.` This sounds like a very problematic design. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @StephenCleary, this is text from test task. Why and what i have no idea. They want me to do it.

Comment: Please re-read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions to make your question better. It would be perfectly fine to say that "my homework should..." since you've *demonstrated* the effort. Showing working implementation with `async` would made it even better question (and I bet you could even get help from Stephen Cleary in such case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements do not sound right.

The async counterpart of `Action` is not `Action<Task>` - it is `Func<Task>`. There are a number of methods in the framework to support my above statement, `Task.Run` being one.

Similarly, for `Action<T>` the async version is `Func<T, Task>`. For `Action<T1, T2>` it is `Func<T1, T2, Task>`. You get the idea.

So, with that in mind your implementation now becomes:

```
public Task Work(Func<Task> input, TaskScheduler uiScheduler)
{
    return input().ContinueWith(e => Console.WriteLine("Done"), uiScheduler);
}
```

Which will allow for calls like this:

```
Task myCustomTaskFollowedByConsoleWriteLine = Work(async () =>
{
    object result = await SomeIOWorkAsync();

    SomeSynchronousCpuBoundWork(result);
},
uiScheduler);
```

You can now even express the other method in terms of `Work(Func<Task>, TaskScheduler)`:

```
public Task Work(Action input, TaskScheduler uiScheduler)
{
    return Work(() => Task.Run(input), uiScheduler);
}
```